# what is layout gutter in android

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

The ViewGroup class talks about gutter. I know the meaning of gutter in English and so based on that I have some vague idea what they are talking about. But I can't quite see what they mean for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the context they're talking about is just an area to dump Views.

[In the example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html):

> Here is a complete implementation of a custom ViewGroup that
>   implements a simple FrameLayout along with the ability to stack
>   children in left and right gutters.

```
public class CustomLayout extends ViewGroup {
    /** The amount of space used by children in the left gutter. */
    private int mLeftWidth;

    /** The amount of space used by children in the right gutter. */
    private int mRightWidth;
}
```

So the example all they're showing is how to make a layout that's split in half in which children can either be placed in the left side or the right side. They choose to call them "gutters".

Then further in the example, they should how to measure out children that are in the left "gutter" and in the right "gutter".  Meaning, there's an area designated on the left side of the Layout and the right side of the Layout.

Other than that, this is not a common term used in ViewGroups or any other layout.  It is used to describe the custom `ViewGroup` that they're building in the example.

Comment: Interesting. That sounds like a misuse of the word then. I imagine a gutter as, say, the small area where a scrollbar might appear since that's what gutters tend to be in real life. But here you think they take the entire area, split it into two halves and call each half a gutter. Let me study the example in that light.

Comment: A "gutter" is usually a long trench that is intended to catch water so it flows out of the way. It's also the trench at the side of a bowling lane that catches bowling balls and the trench between pages in a book. I guess the example author thought it would be a good name for a long section of a layout that you captures Views.

Comment: I get it. A little bit more documentation on their part might have helped. Thanks.